# Intel HAXM is not compatible with Hyper-V?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, hyper-v

I downloaded visual studio's latest release and installed it successfully but 
when I run my xamarin forms project and open `Android Device Manager` in `Visual Studio 2017` and run the emulator it says:

> You are attempting to accelerate the emulator using Intel’s HAXM, but
>   you have Hyper-V enabled in your system settings. Disable Hyper-V by
>   running: 
>   *bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off*
>   in an elevated command prompt and restart your computer before trying
>   again.

However I run this command `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` two to three times and restarted the PC but that is not working. Also I tried to find Hyper-V in windows feature but it is not present there. What could be the solution here? Thanks!

Comment: disable [Core Isolation Memory Integration](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104025-turn-off-core-isolation-memory-integrity-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same on Windows 7 which doesn't even have Hyper-V, I'm praying someone answers this one as I cannot get it working again after trying reinstalling VS and HAXM

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry for late reply. Though I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @Mechamonkey Have you got any solution?

Comment: no sorry @Dungeon, completely stumped

Comment: do you run VMware or Virtualbox?

Comment: neither. 
This was working fine for me using Visual Studio 2017 until I updated a couple of days ago via the VS installer.

Comment: as info I have submitted this issue to MS:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/320540/android-device-warning-haxm-not-compatible-with-hy.html